# Safari -webkit-backface-visibility isn't working properly

Tags: jquery, css, safari, transform

I have a page element that is CSS transforms to flip the front and back of cards.

In Safari, I can't seem to get the front backface to hide or the back to display, likely because the front div's backface isn't hidden as it should be.

It works perfectly in Chrome, but not Safari.

I've found similar issues here, but none of the solutions provided had any effect.

```
.item-front, .item-back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ddolan/V2gvG/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari currently needs -webkit prefixes for `transition` and `transform`. In your fiddle you forgot to prefix `transform-style: preserve-3d;` in your `.item-flipper` rules.

Just add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` and you're good to go in Safari too.

Comment: Thank you, kremalicious! That was it!